# How do I filter a mongo collection on nested field value?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I have a meteor collection with the below structure. This actually comes from a `Meteor-files` collection by `ostrio`.

```
{
 "_id" : "HsXoZ6bxkx5kMcJtm", 
"name" : "trees.jpg", 
"meta" : { "artist_id" : "QkmYdsZsMmRzqTg58" , "artist": "some name"}, 
"mime-type" : "audio/mp3", 
"userId" : "QkmYdsZsMmRzqTg58", 
"_collectionName" : "images" 
}
```

I define a publication

```
Meteor.publish('files.artist', function publishUserImages(){
   return Images.find({meta: {artist_id: this.userId}).cursor;
});
```

I want to filter on the `meta` key, to return all items with `artist_id`.
My current filter will get only those Images where `meta` has the exact value `{artist_id: "QkmYdsZsMmRzqTg58"}`. The filter won't return the item shown above since it the `meta` value has an extra key `artist`

How do I construct an appropriate filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to query a nested field

```
Meteor.publish('files.artist', function publishUserImages(){
   return Images.find({ 'meta.artist_id': this.userId}).cursor;
});
```

The difference is that your query requires whole subdocument match while using dot notation you're just checking one subfield equality.